# Method of Solving for Differential Equations with Trinomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve for $((D^5 + 5D + 4)*(2D^2 + 5D + 2))y = 0$

Answer is $y = c_1*e^{-4x} + c_2*e^{-x} + c_3*e^{-2x} + c_4*e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$

I'm having a hard time looking for a method to solve this; Any hint on how? A solution would be great but I was looking for the name of the method to solve this? I can't seem to find it. its surely not variable seperable; I cant put it in exact equations neither...

Comment: Have you learned characteristic equations for linear ODE with constant coefficients?

Comment: each factor must be zero